# Are there any alternative CIFS implementations for the Windows platform?

Tags: networking, network-shares, samba, open-source

Out of curiosity, is using standard built-in Microsoft Windows file and folder sharing services the only way of running a CIFS/SMB server on a Windows machine or are there alternatives (like open source Samba Win32 builds)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found the answer myself, so let me share it for further reference:

There are Win32 versions of Samba and smbclient available. [This smbclient version](http://www.leepa.io/lpackham/smbclient/) works just fine on Windows 7 32-bit and lets you to access Windows shares from command line without mounting then as network drives. The only problem is it requires cygwin to be installed.

UPDATE: Another problem is that I am still fighting with codepages...

UPDATE2: I have managed to figure out (experimentally) the correct codepages configuration for international non-ASCII setup, this is my smb.conf file that makes it work perfectly:

```
[global]
workgroup = WORKGROUP
unix charset = UTF8
dos charset = UCS-2LE
display charset = UTF8
```

Comment: Thanks for coming back a year later to provide an answer :)

Comment: I could find no answers googling it when I have posted this but now google "samba win32" gives some answers.

Comment: Keep in mind that SMB _is_ a Microsoft protocol, which is why it's so unorthodox to not use the Windows client.  Microsoft does have a [great article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2696547) explaining how to change which version of the client you're using.

Comment: The page you have linked to says "Sorry, the page you requested is not available.", @Jason.

Comment: I actually prefer to disable all protocols but TCP/IP for Windows network interfaces and block all (but critical like DNS) system-network interaction with a firewall to prevent viruses, exploits etc (I still remember viruses that used to infect machines through Windows CIFS implementation vulnerabilities). But I still need to access SAMBA shares on occasion. That's why I am trying to run the SAMBA client on Windows. I also plan to implement a GUI "commander" of my own or a Total Commander plug-in for this when I succeed (I am still fighting with codepage problems and cygwin dependance).

Comment: Update: Gotcha! I have managet to make it work correct with non-ASCII file names, updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

[muCommander](http://www.mucommander.com/) has an indipendent client implementation in Java (based on [JCIFS](https://jcifs.samba.org/)).
I use it often with the transfer verify feature to make sure files are transferred correctly.